# Meteor - button click not updating value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, meteor

I am trying to get a random document in the collection and display it on the page. It is successful every time I load the page, but I want a button to do the work as well.

main.html

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Random Question</h1>
  {{> question}}
</body>

<template name="question">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#each object}}
      {{question}}
      {{a}}
      {{b}}
      {{c}}
      {{d}}
      {{answer}}
      {{points}}
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('quiz');

Template.question.created = function () {

  var random = get_random();

  this.question = new ReactiveDict();
  this.question.set('object', random);
};

function get_random(){
  var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
  var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
  // choose a random item by skipping N items
  var item = Resolutions.findOne({},{
    skip: random
  });
  var objArray = $.makeArray(item);
  return objArray;
}

Template.question.helpers({
  object: function () {
    return get_random();
  }
});

Template.question.events({
  'click button': function (event, template) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    var random = get_random();
    template.question.set('object', random);
  }
});
```

There is no error message when I load the page or click the button.

Any help is appreciated.
Btw, what is the object inside "this.question.set('object', random);". Maybe that's where my issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can considerably simplify your code and also solve your problem by *not* picking a random object in your helper - that will run many times, even when you don't expect it to. Also since you're only viewing a single object, use `{{#with }}` instead of `{{#each }}` - this will avoid the array conversion step.

html:

```
<template name="question">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#with object}}
      {{question}}
      {{a}}
      {{b}}
      {{c}}
      {{d}}
      {{answer}}
      {{points}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './main.html';

Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('quiz');

Template.question.created = function () {
  setRandom(); // initialize the random selection
};

function setRandom(){
  var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
  var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
  Session.set('random',random);
}

Template.question.helpers({
  object: function () {
    return Resolutions.findOne({},{ skip: Session.get('random') });
  }
});

Template.question.events({
  'click button': function (event, template) {
    setRandom();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michel! That did the trick. Isn't session something that people are trying to avoid nowadays? I've heard ReactiveDict is somewhat better. But I also read it somewhere that session is included in ReactiveDict lol

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with Session IMO. You could use a reactive variable in its place.